# Drag and drop function not working correctly with Relative Panels using the Windows 10 SDK

Tags: c#, xaml, drag-and-drop

So I have a collection of colours in a Listview which I can reorder, drag and drop, but dropping on my relative panel will not work. I manually added another colour to the collection and wired up the same drop operation of the relative panel, and it works. I have tried to wire up the drop in code behind onLoad but it still doesn't work. To clarify, the DragEnter and DragLeave functions work correctly. Here's some dummy XAML

```
<grid>
   <ScrollViewer>
      <ListView ItemClick="ItemClickEvent"
            SelectionMode="Extended" IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsSwipeEnabled="True"
            CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" AllowDrop="True"
            IsRightTapEnabled="True">
       </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <RelativePanel DragEnter="RelativePanel_OnDragEnter" DragLeave="RelativePanel_OnDragLeave" AllowDrop="True" Drop="RelativePanel_OnDrop">
       <Viewbox Width="128" Height="128">
           <!-- Some more code -->
       </Viewbox>
    </RelativePanel>
</grid>
```

I was thinking, that it may be because they are different children of the root grid. I then realised that this was dumb of me because the drag enter works.

I'm completely confused here, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: does the RelativePanel_OnDrop fires up? The RelativePanel has no stretch size like the Grid has, I would consider to replace with a grid and remove the Viewbox inside the RelativePanel, at least to test

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello It does not fire up. I just tried it with an empty grid and stackpanel. Still no luck.

Comment: is the drop grid overlapped with the scrollvierver? add row columns to the main grid, does it have a background color (for testing)?

Comment: It's not overlapped. I've tried everything, including making a fresh project. Just no luck